# Create user in office 365 programatically

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I want to create user programtically in order to achieve the following functionality:

Once user is created I need to add more information related to that user in custom list.

Anyone has an idea about it?

Comment: Please check this one -> http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101327/creating-microsoft-external-user-account-using-c

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell for this. 
How to create one or more O365 users by using PowerShell: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt628067.aspx

In the following link they explain how to push items to a Sharepoint list.
https://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2014/05/09/sharepoint-powershell-how-to-create-sharepoint-list-items-in-root-and-in-folders-for-loadperformance-testing/

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a O365 user using [Microsoft Graph API](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_post_users) ,you could make a post request to create user like:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json
```

Below is the request body for your reference:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName":"displayName",
  "mailNickname": "mailNickname",
  "passwordProfile": {
      "password": "Your password"
            },
  "userPrincipalName": "displayName@yourtenant.com",

}
```